# What are the syntax transformation rules of Teradata's "implicit JOIN"?

Tags: sql, teradata

Given this schema:

```sql
create table t (i int, j int);
create table u (i int, j int);
insert into t values (1, 1);
insert into t values (2, 2);
insert into u values (1, 1);
insert into u values (2, 1);
```

It is possible in Teradata to write the following:

```sql
select * from t where t.j = u.j;
```

Which seems to implicitly add the `u` table to the table list. What's actually being executed is this:

```sql
select t.* from t, u where t.j = u.j;
```

Both producing

```
|i  |j  |
|---|---|
|1  |1  |
|1  |1  |
```

Irrespective of whether using this feature is a good idea (and I think it isn't), I can't seem to find any reference to it in the documentation. The documentation seems to always use the latter syntax.

My questions are:

- What is this type of "implicit join" called? (Most people call the output version "implicit join", because it does not use the ANSI JOIN syntax), so here, I'm referring to this "double-implicit join"...
- What are the exact syntactic rules for it?

Comment: Nice one +1, I'm stumped.  I'm also wondering whether this feature were ever actually part of some SQL ANSI standard.

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Would be interesting to know! Apparently, it was supported in old PostgreSQL versions, too: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.0/runtime-config.html#GUC-ADD-MISSING-FROM

Comment: The Postgresql `add_missing_from` documentation has "_However, this behavior is not SQL-standard, and many people dislike it because it can mask mistakes (such as referencing a table where you should have referenced its alias). Set to false for the SQL-standard behavior of rejecting references to tables that are not listed in FROM._" I've never heard of it before, so I assume it has never been part of any old SQL standard.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Teradata development started 1979, in the 70s there was no Standard SQL, yet. One of the query languages was QUEL, designed by the well-known father of Postgres, Michael Stonebraker. It was implemented first in Ingres, the predecessor of Postgres (**Post**-In**gres** used POSTQUEL initially). Teradata implementation  was named TEQUEL and there was no FROM.

This is TEQUEL syntax and still works:

```
RETRIEVE t.j;
```

Your select mixes TEQUEL and SQL, even this works:

```
select t.* where t.j = u.j;
```

It contains enough information for the Parser to resolve table name and column name.

When the parser encounters an unknown table name it searches in the current default database and all the databases referenced by fully qualified objects in this query.
See [Unqualified Object Names](https://docs.teradata.com/r/37meaKdwvl0jrhzrc6FoEw/rxbvZvYMVYt_Pz5wDwIXbQ)

Teradata never dared to remove the old legacy syntax, I wish there was a flag to switch it off.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the history lesson, greatly appreciated :) However, I don't see how that linked "Unqualified Object Names" section explains the behaviour. It says *"because the database name and table name can be derived from the Personnel.Employee reference in the FROM clause."*, so it still assumes standard SQL behaviour where table declarations in the `FROM` clause are required. For example, it doesn't mention adding tables to the `FROM` clause forming cartesian products...

Comment: It's the following section *Omitting Database Names*. There's hardly anything about that deprecated TEQUEL syntax in the manuls.

Comment: The way I read that section, this just explains what happens when tables in the `FROM` clause are not qualified with a database, e.g. `Employee` instead of `Personnel.Employee`... Granted, that also applies to my example where `t` and `u` are also not qualified with a database.

Comment: It does not explicitly mention objects in FROM :-)

Comment: It does not explicitly mention creating cartesian products by *adding objects to FROM*!